# "The ClusterRoleBinding "kubernetes-dashboard" is invalid: roleRef: Invalid value" when deploying Web UI

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy Kubernetes Web UI as described here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/

My system configuration is as follows:

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 3.1.0 (Debian 1:3.1+dfsg-8+deb10u3)
Copyright (c) 2003-2018 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

$ minikube version
minikube version: v1.5.2
commit: 792dbf92a1de583fcee76f8791cff12e0c9440ad-dirty

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.3", GitCommit:"b3cbbae08ec52a7fc73d334838e18d17e8512749", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-11-13T11:23:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.2", GitCommit:"c97fe5036ef3df2967d086711e6c0c405941e14b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T19:09:08Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

After starting the minukube cluster `minikube start` I created a Service Account and ClusterRoleBinding as described here: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md

```
$ nano dashboard-adminuser.yaml
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
```

```
$ kubectl apply -f dashboard-adminuser.yaml
$ nano dashboard-adminuser.yaml
```

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
```

```
$ kubectl apply -f dashboard-adminuser.yaml
```

Now I execute:

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta6/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

or

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

and get the following output:

```
namespace/kubernetes-dashboard configured
serviceaccount/kubernetes-dashboard configured
service/kubernetes-dashboard configured
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-certs configured
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf configured
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder configured
configmap/kubernetes-dashboard-settings configured
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard configured
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard configured
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard configured
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard configured
service/dashboard-metrics-scraper configured
deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper configured
The ClusterRoleBinding "kubernetes-dashboard" is invalid: roleRef: Invalid value: rbac.RoleRef{APIGroup:"rbac.authorization.k8s.io", Kind:"ClusterRole", Name:"kubernetes-dashboard"}: cannot change roleRef
```

What happened and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

issue is you missed this note :

> NOTE: apiVersion of ClusterRoleBinding resource may differ between Kubernetes versions.
>
> Prior to Kubernetes v1.8 the apiVersion was rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1.

This should solve this problem.

#### Edit1:

[this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66353) issue talks about same problem.  specifically [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66353#issuecomment-407596305) comment. talks about

> Role bindings are immutable

Cause here is

`dashboard-adminuser.yaml` sets roleRef.

and

[yaml file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta6/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml) you are applying later has roleRef in same namespace.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: kubernetes-dashboard
    namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
```

Comment: My kubernetes version is 1.16.2, so I can use `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1`. I also checked `kubectl api-versions` which showed me both `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1` and `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1`, so it's not the case.

Comment: After your edit I found dashboard project readme with the deployment instructions: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard. They are slightly different from the official kubernetes.io docs. I was able to start the Web UI process without errors, though I have another issue that prevents me from logging into it. So, I accept your answer as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 28):

The error "cannot change roleRef" was referring to the fact that the ClusterRoleBinding already existed.

Try deleting the existing ClusterRoleBinding  *kubernetes-dashboard*

Run below to delete existing:

```
kubectl delete clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard
```

After that try installing again. Let us know if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I ran this command `kubectl delete clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard`, then  `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml` and still getting the same error.

Comment: This was the solution for me!

Comment: I still get this error. I use this manifest: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-rc2/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml

Answer (score 5):

For me work it deleting the existing cluster role:

`kubectl delete clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard`

Answer (score 1):

Just reproduced.

1) created namespace, ServiceAccount and ClusterRolebinding

```
cat dashboard-adminuser.yaml 
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
```

2) apply it

```
kubectl apply -f dashboard-adminuser.yaml 
namespace/kubernetes-dashboard created
serviceaccount/admin-user created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/admin-user unchanged
```

3) Install dashboard

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta6/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
namespace/kubernetes-dashboard unchanged
serviceaccount/kubernetes-dashboard created
service/kubernetes-dashboard created
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-certs created
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf created
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder created
configmap/kubernetes-dashboard-settings created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard created
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard created
service/dashboard-metrics-scraper created
deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper created
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting this error too, solved by running dashboard through minikube:

```
minikube dashboard
```

Output:

```
  Verifying dashboard health ...
  Launching proxy ...
  Verifying proxy health ...
  Opening http://127.0.0.1:34653/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ in your default browser...
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but my goal was to set up it manually using the guide not relying on minikube's implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Run:

kubectl delete clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard

...AFTER the apply -f command, not before.